# Base64 encoded @font-face for Tumblr

Tags: css, base64, font-face, tumblr, webfonts

Since Tumblr does not accept webfont files that are hosted on other domains, I am trying to import the files directly with Base64 encoding.

This is the format I have used:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontName';
  src: url(data:application/vnd.ms-fontobject;base64,[BASE64 CODE]);
  src: url(data:font/woff2;base64,[BASE64 CODE]) format('woff2'),
       url(data:application/font-woff;base64,[BASE64 CODE]) format('woff'),
       url(data:application/x-font-truetype;base64,[BASE64 CODE]) format('truetype');
}
```

I have tried pasting this with the appropriate code to the Tumblr CSS editor, HTML editor in a style tag and in a external stylesheet without any success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is is being filtered out by Tumblr (when saving/submitting)? Or is it present on the actual page but does it just not work? [Do you have a example page?]

Comment: @Philip It does not seem like it is being filtered out. In the latest version it's loaded through an external stylesheet hosted on static.tumblr.com, which is my preferred method since the Base64 clutters the code. Here is the site I'm trying to import the webfont to: khrelated.tumblr.com

Comment: When inspecting the page with Chrome, I see multiple error like this: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://khrelated.tumblr.com' is therefore not allowed access.` It seems that even the file itself is not loaded because of this missing policy header

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Base64 encoder I was using produced code that did not work. For anyone encountering the same issue, try using this encoder: https://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/